# Return a Revenue Total from previous month using SSRS Expression

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Is there a way to return previous month's Revenue as an Opening balance?
For Example:

Create an expression to pull the revenue field for all In progress deals on the last day of the previous month using an expression

I can get the the last day using this expression, however i dont know how to add in the revenue field

```
=dateadd("m",0,dateserial(year(Today),month(Today),0))
```

Please can someone help me in pulling the total revenue recorded on last day of previous month?

Comment: You need to edit your question and add a lot more info such as what your source data looks like, what does you dataset output look like, some sample data and your expected output based on the sample data. Then people will be able to help

Answer (score 0):

i just wanted to know if it is possible. i dont need a lecture.
A simple yes or No would suffice - i got it working.